# Why is the autograder giving me errors for CodeHS 8.4.9: Owls Part 2?

Tags: python

Here's the assignment:

> This program is an extension of your previous ‘Owls’ program.
> In addition to just reporting how many words contained the word owl, you should report the indices at which the words occurred!
> Here’s what an example run of your program might look like:

```
Enter some text: Owls are so cool! I think snowy owls might be my favorite. Or maybe spotted owls.
There were 3 words that contained "owl".
They occurred at indices: [0, 7, 15]
```

> As you can see from the output, you’ll have to use another list to store the indices where you found the words containing “owl”.
> The enumerate function might also come in handy!

Here's my code now:

```
def owl_count(text):
owl_lower = text.lower()
owl_split = owl_lower.split()
count = 0
index = 0
sec_in = []
owl = "owl"
for i in range(len(owl_split)):
    if owl in owl_split[index]:
        count = count + 1
        sec_in.append(index)
    index = index + 1
print("There were " + str(count) + " words that contained owl.")
return "They occurred at indices: " + str(sec_in)

text = "I really like owls. Did you know that an owl's eyes are more than twice as big as the eyes of other birds of comparable weight? And that when an owl partially closes its eyes during the day, it is just blocking out light? Sometimes I wish I could be an owl."
print(owl_count(text))
```

When I run the code it's perfectly fine. But when it has to go through the autograder it says I'm doing things wrong. And this input is what's getting me the least errors.
Here are some of the ones I used before if it helps:

> Owlets are baby owls. Baby peafowls are called peachicks.

> Owls are so cool! I think snowy owls might be my favorite. Or maybe spotted owls.

> I think owls are pretty cool

[Here's the link to the code I used to help me.](https://github.com/Th3-H4xx0r/CodeHs-Unit-8-9/blob/master/echo%20%22%23%20CodeHs-Answers-Unit8-9%22%20%3E%3E%20README.md%20git%20init%20git%20add%20README.md%20git%20commit%20-m%20%22first%20commit%22%20git%20remote%20add%20origin%20https:/github.com/Th3-H4xx0r/8.4.13:%20Owls%2C%20Part%202)

[First autograder picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woqL6.png)

[Second autograder picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikRkT.png)

[Third autograder picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuRq5.png)

Comment: whiy do you have a for loop (that tracks the words in the text), and then have a separate variable which you increment  - you don't need both. You also don't need count - just use len(sec_in) Without knowing what text the autograder uses, and what results it thinks you should generate it is tough to tell exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I think the biggest issue is that your code prints the count line, and then returns the indices line. If the autograder simply executes your function and ignores the return value it will ignore the indices.
Note that the example code you cite prints both lines - and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code has a lot of redundant variables - this is a tidied up version of your code - it should work exactly the same as yours :

I think the biggest issue is that your code prints the count line, and then returns the indices line. If the autograder simply executes your function and ignores the return value it will ignore the indices. Note that the example code you cite prints both lines - and doesn't return anything. This is corrected in the version below.

Note that this code uses enumerate - it is a very good function to get into the habit of using if you need the contents of a list and you need to track the index in the list too.

```
def owl_count(text):
    owl_lower = text.lower()
    owl_split = owl_lower.split()
    sec_in = []
    owl = "owl"
    for index, word in enumerate(owl_split):
        if owl in word:
           sec_in.append(index)
    print("There were " + str(len(sec_in)) + " words that contained \"owl\".")
    print("They occurred at indices: " + str(sec_in))

text = "I really like owls. Did you know that an owl's eyes are more than twice as big as the eyes of other birds of comparable weight? And that when an owl partially closes its eyes during the day, it is just blocking out light? Sometimes I wish I could be an owl."
owl_count(text)
```

There is a more efficient method to solve the problem, without a lot of variables that are only used to create others - and you have a for loop which could/should be a comprehension - so an even better version would be :

```
def owl_count(text):
    sec_in = [index for index, word in enumerate(text.lower().split())
                      if 'owl' in word]
    print("There were " + str(len(sec_in)) + " words that contained \"owl".")
    print("They occurred at indices: " + str(sec_in))
```

Update - 02/11/2020 - 14:12 - The expected result from the autograder expects quotes around the word 'owl' in the first output message. The above code has been updated to include those quotes.

Comment: Thank you. I entered this code but the autograder just did the same response. I don't know why it's doing this because I don't think this has ever happened before.

Comment: Ok = for a start your count message doesn't include "" - see latest edit.

Comment: It's okay. I talked to my comp sci teacher about it and he overrode it. He didn't know what was wrong with it either lol.